# Laravel Docker: No such host is known

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-artisan

I'm running Docker to host a Laravel website, but running into a problem when migrating the database.

The site I'm testing runs fine in a browser but when I run `php artisan migrate` I get:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

When I change the host to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, I can migrate the database but the site no longer runs in my browser. Is there a way to get both to work so I don't have to keep editing .env?

Comment: Are you using docker-compose?

Comment: No - I have the docker-compose.yml but haven't changed anything inside.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding some of the fundamentals i.e. `php artisan migrate` migrates to my local environment, and not the container? Whereas migrating using sail would be the right approach e.g. in linux terminal: `./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate` (which works)?

Comment: I guess your php, nginx, and database containers are not all running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you run command "php artisan migrate" in docker container**

try this :

1. `docker exec -it YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME bash`
2. `cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/LARAVEL`
3. `php artisan migrate`

I hope it work